# Low scales models aren’t drawn in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I draw a sphere using this code

```
function sphere(cena,x,y,z,radius,colorr)
  {
    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, 10, 10);

    var materiall = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: colorr , side: THREE.DoubleSide} );


    var cir = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, materiall ) 

    cir.position.x=x;
    cir.position.y=y;
    cir.position.z=z;

    cena.add( cir );

    return cir ;    
  }
```

Now I am drawing a sphere with radius 10^(-6)

```
var um=Math.pow(10,-6);
sphere(scene,0,0,0,um*3.5,'green')
```

Nothing is drawn. The same is for um*30. Only from um*300 the sphere appears. Camera near is set 0.000001

I need that scales, what to do?

---

Lines, by the way are drawn well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you position your camera. Try it with this code:

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.000001, 1 );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var um = Math.pow( 10, - 6 );
    camera.position.z = um * 10;
  
    var mesh = sphere( scene, 0, 0, 0, um * 3.5 , 'green' );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}

function sphere(cena,x,y,z,radius,colorr) {

    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( radius, 10, 10);

    var materiall = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: colorr , side: THREE.DoubleSide} );


    var cir = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, materiall );

    cir.position.x=x;
    cir.position.y=y;
    cir.position.z=z;

    cena.add( cir );

    return cir;    
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think the key is 'antialias: true' parameter, that is not set in my renderer

Comment: No. It still doesn’t work(I've set position of camera at the first time, the same as you). Screen at 10^-5 : https://imgur.com/OWGWCXI segments 20

Comment: Please demonstrate this with an editable live example. https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Comment: Still checking.. In jsfiddle all works fine. Difference between Your code and mine is orbit controls(in jsfidle work). Maybe, while I searching You have any idea what can cause that deformations, I shown in picture?

Comment: What version of `three.js` are you using?

Comment: I tried the same script tag as You, and nothing changed

Comment: You, also, don’t need to use scene.add to add sphere

Comment: Come on! You changed the function - `SphereBufferGeometry`  You can’t say it instantly?

Comment: Oh, I was not aware that using `SphereGeometry` is the culprit. But now I see why. `SphereGeometry` is created from `SphereBufferGeometry`. When doing so, vertices are merged. Since the scale of your geometry is so small, the algorithm merges all vertices into one.

Comment: Well, now I know. Thank You

Comment: Why do you need such ridiculously small geometries?

Comment: You can have a unit sphere, which is scaled, then you can use either the normal or the buffer geometries.